# Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook giving an error at Powers-shell script

Tags: powershell-4.0, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am new to power-shell and cmldt.

I registered a power-shell script(.ps1) name like "Invoke-xxDevopDt" as azure RunBooks that  associated with an azure Automation Account.This RunBooks scheduled to run at another data for do some work. Below is my power-shell script(.ps1) which i used to register "Invoke-xxDevopDt" (RunBook) by using 'Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook' as below

```
param ( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$resourceGroup='rsgrp_test',

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$automationAccountName='Azureaucnt-test',

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [datetime]$startDateTime='01/05/2021 6:00:00 PM' ,
    
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$vmResourceIds='/subscriptions/5454-7d8e-xxx-b628-yy3232/resourceGroups/TSTDEV/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/TSTDevVM',

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [String] $IncludedKBs='4588962',

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [datetime] $vmRestartDateTime='01/06/2021 4:00:00 PM',

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [String] $description = "Automated trigger from C# Program"

)
    #do Login-AzAccount  to login azure subcription  
    ....    
    #setting data for   
    $AddMinutes = 7
    
    # creating an scheduling and registering 
    $scheduleName = "testAPP_devopsSchedule_" + "$(Get-Date $vmRestartDateTime -UFormat %Y-%m-%d_%A_%H-%M)"
    $devopsSchedule = New-AzAutomationSchedule -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
                                                      -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName `
                                                      -Name $scheduleName `
                                                      -StartTime ($vmRestartDateTime.AddMinutes($AddMinutes)) `
                                                      -Onetime -Verbose
                                                      
    #Createing a param for registering another PS-script as RunBook with automation-acnt
    $params = @{"serverList"=$vmResourceIds;"testMessage"="test";"description"="Invoking Automation from Automation Account"}
    #register 'Invoke-xxDevopDt' is like a ps-script at runBook of automation-acnt
    Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook –AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName `
                        –Name 'Invoke-xxDevopDt' –ScheduleName $devopsSchedule.Name –Parameters $params `
                        -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup
```

But, above ps-script gave an ERROR as "**Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Invoke-xxDevopDt'**."

Pls help

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please add '-debug' in the command to get error message in detail?

Comment: I am using vs code IDE and power-shell extension for debugging above power-shell script. 
Actually 'Invoke-xxDevopDt' is like a  ps-script and store it at runbook of automation account. in script, i am just registering by using "Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook"
Thanks,

Comment: Could you please tell me if you have a runbook named `Invoke-xxDevopDt`?

Comment: Besdies, is that you want to create a schedule for one runbook?

Comment: Thanks for replay @Jim Xu.
Yes.. same named runbook had and try to scheduling that runbook by above script.

Comment: Ok. According to my understanding, you have created an Azure rubook `Invoke-xxDevopDt` in Azure automation account. Now you want to create a schedule for the runbook. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226856/discussion-between-anirban-goswami-and-jim-xu).

Comment: Hi. According to my test, it is ok for me. My script : https://pastebin.pl/view/728391e7. My result: ihttps://ibb.co/Lxk7Yh0

Comment: Thank @Jim..
did u create that above ps-script and saved as runbook of azure automation-account then u tried to Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook above runbook with -Name at another ps-script ?

Comment: yes, I did that

Comment: Thank @Jim ... 
I can see from urs ps-script that u are using "Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook" with -Name parameter as 'test' .  
Did u create a runbookk with another ps-script as name 'Test' ?

Comment: yes. I create a runbook named `test` and create a schedule for it. It works.

Comment: Thank @Jim for replay and help..
I have to check throughout on above ps-script and need to figure out why error is coming at last line..

Thanks,

Comment: Hello, @AnirbanGoswami, have you solved the issue? if it's solved, please add an answer:).

Comment: Yes.. It was solved.. Actually  it was a problem of white space and i was using vs code IDE for running , debugging ps script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an answer to close this issue.

At our side, we can successfully register it. And as per op's comment, the issue is due to white space, and now it can work.